# Changing Div height using Javascript on IE not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble getting IE to resize my div in an onload function.  onload is definitely firing and the alerts below are showing the right values, but it isn't reflected on screen.  It works fine on both firefox and chrome (as usual).

```
var height = document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight;
alert(height);

document.getElementById("extra").style.height = height+80 + "px";                             
document.getElementById("transparency").style.height =  height + "px";
document.getElementById("navtrans").style.height = height+80 + "px";
alert(document.getElementById("navtrans").style.height);
```

Any tips to get it working on IE?

Comment: Does the height change in IE via plain CSS? Probably it's a CSS issue and not a javascript one.

Comment: Should work like that, maybe give us a fiddle or more code :)

Comment: adding a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: It probably is css isn't it ;).  My head was so buried in the problem I didn't think of changing the css.  Unfortunately I've got for fatherly duties now, but I will try afresh when I return.  Thanks for the jsfiddle tip, it look interesting!

Here is the CSS for navtrans: -

div.navtrans {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 font-weight: bold;
 min-height: 765px;
 top: 168px;
 background-color: #3173C1;
 filter: alpha(opacity = 58);
 opacity: 0.58;
 width: 197px;
 z-index: 8;
 position: absolute;
}

Comment: Hi Guys, Sorry life got in the way of this.  I am testing with IE8.  The site in question is here if you want a look http://www.siroccosoftware.com/awesome/page?id=3 .  I tried changing CSS, but I couldn't find a way to make it work

Comment: in IE8 your site is working fine. I tested it myself, event in IE7 height is working.